# Getting Null value for SQL xml cast in parsing a element

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

getting Null value for xml cast in parsing a element "ErrorType"

I have this XML stored in  my SQL database column.

```
<Response>
    <ISSuccessfulPingResponse>false</ISSuccessfulPingResponse>
    <PingResponse>
        <PriceResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://www.test.com/pasd/test.xsd">
            <Result>ERROR</Result>
            <ErrorType>XML Validation</ErrorType>
            <ErrorDescription> equal to 5.</ErrorDescription>
            <out>0</out>
        </PriceResult>
    </PingResponse>
</Response>
```

and I tried to run an SQL script for getting value for element "ErrorType", but  I am receiving null value.

```
SELECT  Cast(Result as xml).value ('(/Response/PingResponse/PriceResult/ErrorType)[1]', 'varchar(100)' ) as result  from  getresults
where Id=23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `PriceResult` and all of the descendant elements without prefix (including `ErrorType`) are in the namespace `https://www.test.com/pasd/test.xsd`, so you should be able to use [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx) here, for example :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('https://www.test.com/pasd/test.xsd' as d)
SELECT Cast(Result as xml).value ('
    (/Response/PingResponse/d:PriceResult/d:ErrorType)[1]
', 'varchar(100)' ) as result 
from getresults where Id=23
```

Basically, the codes defined a prefix `d` that mapped to the namespace URI using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, and then use it (prefix `d`) to reference elements in the namespace.